# ¿Como manejar el lifetime en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

He realizado un  código para que cada usuario tenga una sesión única, para ello cree un campo en la BD llamado "estado" y ejecuto un Store Procedure para que cada vez que un usuario haga login se ejecute el procedure y el campo se actualice a "1" y asi mismo para la parte del Logout que cada vez cierre sesion el usuario se actualice a "0".

**Mi Problema radica en el** momento que el usuario se encuentre inactivo por un tiempo, pues Laravel muestra "Page expired" y el campo de la base de datos no se actualiza queda con el valor "1" y obviamente no puede loguearse porque ese campo debería estar en "0" para hacerlo.

Como puedo tomar el valor del **lifetime** que se encuentra en config/session.php y manipularlo en el LoginController para que cada vez que expire la pagina por inactividad se ejecute el procedimieneto almacenado y así pueda cambiar el valor de la base de datos.

Este es mi LoginController

```
    public function authenticated(Request $request)
   {   
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        if(Auth::check()){
            Auth::logoutOtherDevices($request->input('password'));
            DB::select('CALL actualizarestados(?)',array(Auth::user()->id));
        }

        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if ($this->auth->attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember')))
            {
                $usuarios=User::findOrFail(Auth::user()->id);

            if($usuarios->estado!=1)
            {
                DB::select('CALL actualizarestados(?)',array(Auth::user()->id));
                return redirect(self::redirectPath());
            }
            else
            {
                $this->auth->logout();
                Session::flush();
                return redirect()->route('login')->with('danger', 'Usuario Logueado anteriormente');
            }


            } 

            return redirect()->route('login')->with('danger', 'Error de usuario o Contrasena');

    }

   public function logout(Request $request)
   {
     DB::select('CALL actualizarestados(?)',array(Auth::user()->id));

     $this->guard()->logout();

     $request->session()->invalidate();

     return $this->loggedOut($request) ?: redirect('/');
   }
```

**O que solución me aconsejan?**

Comment: Que pasa si un usuario hace login en su computador y va a otro lugar y quiere entrar desde su teléfono, no puede? Tiene que esperar que expire la sesión o volver a su casa a hacer logout para entrar desde otro dispositivo? O sesion unica sería que cuando entra desde el teléfono, termina la sesión anterior del usuario en el computador?

Comment: Exacto si hace login en un dispositivo no lo puede hacer en otro dispositivo o en otro navegador, lo unico que no puedo controlar es que cuando expira la pagina por inactividad el disparador no se ejecuta para poder modificar el campo de la base de datos, entonces me gustaria saber como manejar cuando expira la pagina y vi que se puede con Config::get('session.lifetime'); pero no se en donde utilizarlo.

Comment: no sé si ya pudiste resolver tu problema? Pues yo tengo la misma necesidad y no sé cómo hacer que se modifique un campo de la base de datos al cerrarse automáticamente la sesión.